# Eloquent sum of foreign key column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The models I have are : **Invoice** - **Credit_note** - **Payment**

- An Invoice hasMany Credit_notes
- Each Credit_note has a single Payment
- A Payment is not directly related to a Credit_note

What I need to do is to calculate **the sum of the Payments(amount) of the Credit_notes of an Invoice**.

With the relations I currently have in place, I can load all the Credit_notes (with their Payments) of an Invoice.

```
Credit_note::with(['payment'])->where('invoice_id', $i->id)
```

I could then sum the amounts by hand... but, is there a way to directly return the sum with the query ?

I tried to add a `->sum('payment.amount')` or something similar, with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `->get('cn_total')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
$sum = Credit_note::with(['payment:id,amount'])
            ->where('invoice_id', $i->id)
            ->get()
            ->pluck('payment.amount')
            ->sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum = Credit_note::with([
        'payments' => function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('payment_id, SUM(payments.amount) AS cn_total')->groupBy('payment_id');
        },
    ])
    ->where('invoice_id', $i->id)->get()->pluck('payments.cn_total')->sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Credit_note`  model make this function

```
public function sum_of_payment(){
    $result=0;
    $paiments=$this->payment()->get();

    foreach($paiments as $paiment){
        $result+=$paiment->amount;
    }
    return $result;

}
```

then you can get SUM like this

```
$sum=Credit_note::with(['payment'])->where('invoice_id', $i->id)->first()->sum_of_payment();
```